# wsl-terminal - missing rvm in it's $PATH

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using [wsl terminal](https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal), which is awesome and a life saver compared to the default Windows WSL terminal emulator.

I am not able to get Ruby's rvm environment to initialize.

In the default Windows WSL terminal emulator, it works:

```
one@AUS-LT-384:~/github/sp6-api$ which rvm
/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm
```

But not in the wsl-terminal emulator:

```
one@AUS-LT-384:~/github/sp6-api$ which rvm
one@AUS-LT-384:~/github/sp6-api$
```

From what I can see, they both use the same bash files. But the `wsl-terminal` does not have rvm in it's `$PATH`.

Why is this and what it the proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but you can fix it by changing your PATH. Add this line to your $HOME/.profile:  export PATH="/usr/share/rvm/bin:$PATH".